# Host docker nginx multiple apps on same host Ubuntu

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to manage reverse proxy (**Nginx**) with multiple Independent webapps on the same host.
Means I have 4 webapps that are hosted on containers separately via docker-compose file and behind with Nginx. How I can handle this scenario, like I have 4 different environments (dev/qa/uat/prod) all are have septate apps, app1/app2/app3/app4 which have their own Nginx instances, all should be deployed on same Host Ubuntu(20.4)

When I run docker-compose-app1.yml its up and run as expected and I can browse (localhost --> https://localhost/login) same as host ip as well BUT

**Problem statement:** When I run docker-compose-app2.yml it gives following error

> Container app2_nginx   Starting
> 2.0s  Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint app2_nginx
> (18b62acf9312fd57cad9979bd0ebde963ff57f32a7489b11faacee4cf4b02b97):
> Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated The terminal
> process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> -Command docker compose -f "docker-compose-app2.yml" up -d --build" terminated with exit code: 1.

app1 Docker file (same for all web app)

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app

USER node
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker-compose-app1.yml (same for all except image/container/ssl certificates and app host port)

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:   
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes: 
      - ./site:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/app.com.crt:/etc/nginx/app1.com.crt
      - ./nginx/app.com.key:/etc/nginx/app1.com.key
    # environment:
      # SITES: 'app.com=app_ssl:80'
      # FORCE_HTTPS: "true"      
    depends_on:
      - app1
    container_name: app1_nginx

  app1:    
    image: app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9200:3000
      # - 801:80
    container_name: app1
```

Default.conf for app1

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.app1.com;
        index index.html;
            # root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        error_log /etc/nginx/app1_errors.log;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
      }
    }
    server { # This new server will watch for traffic on 443        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name app1.com;            
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/app1.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/app1.com.key;        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; 
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;       
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;    
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://hosyip:9200;
          error_log /etc/nginx/app1_errors.log;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }
```

Folder structure for webapp1, same as reset of other 3 Webapps

```
- app1
- nginx
-- nginx.conf
- docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you publish all container ports to the same host port, thats what the error is saying

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated
```

When you run the for first time `docker-compose up` there is no issue, but its subsequent one requests the `same host port`

In these cases, you could tackle this by not explicitily binding the ports to a specific host port, but instead let the system find the free ones.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  nginx:   
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
# NOT explicit bind
      - 80
      - 443
    volumes: 
      - ./site:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/app.com.crt:/etc/nginx/app1.com.crt
      - ./nginx/app.com.key:/etc/nginx/app1.com.key
    # environment:
      # SITES: 'app.com=app_ssl:80'
      # FORCE_HTTPS: "true"      
    depends_on:
      - app1
    container_name: app1_nginx

  app1:    
    image: app1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    restart: always
    # There is no need to expose these ports since you use nginx for load balancing
    # ports:
      # - 9200:3000
      # - 801:80
    container_name: app1
```

Since the containers are able to perform dns discovery you could alter your nginx default.conf to find the container

**default.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.app1.com;
        index index.html;
            # root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        error_log /etc/nginx/app1_errors.log;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
      }
    }
    server { # This new server will watch for traffic on 443        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name app1.com;            
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/app1.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/app1.com.key;        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1; 
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=500;       
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;    
        location / {
          # proxy_pass http://hosyip:9200;
          # Docker can resolve the hostname, you can use the container name
          proxy_pass http://app1:3000;
          error_log /etc/nginx/app1_errors.log;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }
```

---

After `docker-compose up` your OS will assign `random ports` for the nginx container, so no conflict will arise. An example

[image]

To access app1 `curl localhost:49155`

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, let me try this and ill update here.

Comment: Hello @SaadAwan, I was curious if the answer provided the expected behavior, or it needs some modifications?

Comment: thanks for following up, Yes I am on it and ill give you update shortly

Comment: Hi @Tolis, I have implement what you mentioned in both files like in docker-compose.yml file: under Nginx ports - 80  - 443 and under app1 ports commentedout # ports:  # - 9200:3000 
and after that in default.conf file
 proxy_pass http://app1:3000; when I run the docker-compose file it run perfectly and up both containers Nginx and app and but and nginx container assgin the ports as expected but when I browser the site app1 with DNS its says "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: @SaadAwan Thanks for the feedback. I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: also now there is nothing in the containers logs as well to identity the issue, issue is in nginx or app1?

Comment: following and waiting.

Comment: @SaadAwan Hello, how are you trying to access the container?

Comment: I am trying to access App container with DNS like APPDOMAIN.COM, the problem starts when I tried to NOT explicit bind the ports of nginx containers in docker compose file as mentioned above.

Comment: @SaadAwan With no explicit bind you need to specify the correct port also, check the end of my answer. Run docker ps to see the port that the OS assigned

Comment: yes exactly, on my system nginx is running under random port 49274 and when i curl localhost:49274 it says
 <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.6</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @SaadAwan Hmm have you tried browsing the site at https:// localhost:HTTPS_PORT

Comment: Meaning the exposed docker port for https

Comment: Yes: curl localhost:49273
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.6</center>

Comment: curl https://localhost:49273
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: I browse https://38.242.233.136:49273 on my browser and after 3, 4 min my app page loads, BUT my website SSL certificate got cross with red color? Why I am not able to access my app with domain/DNS ?

Comment: @SaadAwan I don't know about this. This has to do with the legitemacy of the certificates. It doesn't have to do with docker I mean. Did this work before?

Comment: Yes exactly it works fine previously as per my above mentioned docker-compose and Nginx file, when I write app1.com in browser it redirect me to https://app1.com with Green correct and secure SSL, After doing some changes as mentioned the result is here

Comment: So does it work, finally?

Comment: NO: after modification in files as per your suggestion I browse 38.242.233.136:49273 on my browser and after 3, 4 min my app page loads, BUT my website SSL certificate got cross with red color? Why I am not able to access my app with domain/DNS with green SSL lock?

Comment: When you write app1.com:49273 what does it show?

Comment: Yes its works when I write app1.com:49273 it redirect to https with correct ssl certificate. Now my last question why it not accessible through ONLY DNS why i add it to Nginx port ? if I give website url to someone else or client its very annoying to add and remember port as well

Comment: @SaadAwan  When you add only DNS the port is defined automatically. Port 80 for http and port 443 for https. Since it listens to a different port now ( 49273,) you have to define it explicitly

Comment: so what happened when i again release/update nginx container so it assigned different port?

Comment: @SaadAwan  Probably yes. But at this point I think we moved past from the scope of the question. You should probably create a new one for the further details. If the answer solved the issue please approve and upvote the answer